# Why does the windows 8 task manager seem to freeze?

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

Several times I've seen the task manager appear frozen in Windows 8. It doesn't update, and generally shows double-digit CPU usage. Closing it and reopening it doesn't usually help, but rebooting generally does. How does this happen, and how do I fix it?

I can confirm that the task manager update speed is changed to "Paused" (Windows 8 Enterprise, not sure if this also happens in Windows 8.1) when the screen saver is activated.

Personally I consider this a bug because the the update remains paused after the screen is unlocked.

Comment: Is the updating Paused (in View menu)?

Comment: Yep, and changing that then fixes it. But I don't know how it gets into that state in the first place. Maybe there's a hotkey for changing the view to Paused?

Comment: I've noticed mine pausing when memory usage gets very high. I suspect Windows does this automatically to prevent Task Manager from taking up that much more processor/memory if it's invoked on a heavily loaded system to avoid sending over the edge into an outright freeze/stall/crash. On restart the system should be in a less heavily used state and so be unpaused.

Comment: I find this incredibly obnoxious.  Would love to hear if there's a way to force it to never pause.

Comment: It cannot be pausing when resources are being hogged... if that were so, then every time I noticed it being paused, Memory or CPU would be capped because it paused during the bad time. But it's often indicating very low usage (no problems) which is confusing when I glance at it to see why my computer is behaving poorly now.

Comment: It seems to me that the Windows 8 Task Manager goes into paused mode when the computer gets locked.

Comment: happened to me first time ever.. and my cpu was at 100% for a while , one application was really hogging the cpu in one of those "close program or wait for it" states... So this pause seems to have happened in response to cpu usage, not memory usage

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've found my task manager doing this as well.  Not sure how it got paused, but when I set the  update speed to normal it gets going again.

Edit: To change this setting, go to View > Update Speed in the top menu.

Comment: Unpausing it definitely fixes it. Still no idea why it gets paused, but I like K.A.'s hypothesis above.

Comment: I'm also wondering how it got paused. It seems like a bug, or maybe a keyboard shortcut that I don't know about that I might've triggered by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening for me also. It was probably connected with my screen going off, or the sleep, or something along that. So it was semi-random for me.

But it also seems that I have my local account created before I got it connected to the microsoft account, and maybe there is a problem with access to this folder in registry of the Task manager.
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager

Or what I did is, that I Open up task manager, setup everything the way I want it (unpaused the task manager View > Update Speed in the top menu.), checked, that the saves are working (you can see it clearly when you are playing with the "DefaultTab" property also from top menu)
And then, through the advanced settings dialog remove write rights, so nothing can change it again.
[image: dialog for removing the rights]